# List of reserved words in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reserved-words

Is there any more complete list than [Mozilla's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) about reserved words?

It lacks words like *parseFloat*, *toString*, *prototype*, etc.

Comment: Follow the links to the ecma script 5.1 pdf, 7.6.1; reserved words

Comment: Or look at the [Annotated ES5's Section 7.6.1](http://es5.github.com/#x7.6.1) if you don't want to look at a PDF, it is an HTML version of the ECMA-262 5.1 standard document.

Comment: @DanD. That link seems to have gone away.

Comment: @phuzi It moved to https://es5.github.io/#x7.6.1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`parseFloat`, `toString` and `prototype` are **not** reserved words. Just because they sometimes have a special meaning, doesn't mean you can't  declare variables with their names;

```
var prototype = "foo"; // no error.
```

The [ES5 standard](https://es5.github.io/#x7.6.1) contains a list of reserved words as well, but it should match the list given by MDN:

```
break, do, instanceof, typeof, case, else, new, var, catch, finally, return, 
void, continue, for, switch, while, debugger, function, this, with, default,
if, throw, delete, in, try

class, enum, extends, super, const, export, import
```

It might also be of interest to you that the [strict varient of ES5](https://es5.github.io/#C) adds additional words to the *reserved* list;

> The identifiers `"implements", "interface", "let", "package", "private", "protected", "public", "static", and "yield"` are classified as `FutureReservedWord` tokens within strict mode code. (section 7.6.1.2).