# Passing AJAX arguments to JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
function myFunction(action, arguments){

$.get(action, arguments)

}

myFunction("link/to/mypage", { "idCustomer": "123", "junk": $.now })
```

Expected connection:

```
link/to/mypage?idCustomer=123&junk=random
```

Actual result:

```
link/to/mypage
```

Why is this? How can I solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: I get `/link/to/mypage?idCustomer=123&junk=1373529858593` (http://jsfiddle.net/fZVZn/)

Comment: I don't know what to say... In my context, changing from arguments to args changed the behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arguments` is a reserved word in JavaScript. Change it to something else and try again!

Comment: thanks! Didn't know that! Will mark as correct as soon as I can.

Comment: @Eric: Can you tell me the all reserved word in javascript ? A website reference perhaps ?

Comment: @SnakeEyes Sure, check out [this thread here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397951/list-of-reserved-words)